# Can I release a 1.x update if my package is on 2.x? (PyPi)

Tags: python, pypi

Example: `PackageX` on PyPi has major version 2, but a lot of users are still using 1.x and in need of a security patch. Can a 1.x update be released even if the package is currently released on 2.x?

Comment: The upload should work. But if your users on 1.0.3 just `pip install --update PackageX`, they're going to be updated to 2.0.1, not 1.0.4, unless they explicitly ask for 1.0.4 (which many of them probably don't know how to do). Is that acceptable?

Comment: That's acceptable in my case, yes. Do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere that it works, but it's implied by the fact that the docs on [upload](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/packageindex.html#package-index) don't say that it _doesn't_ work. As far as the database is concerned, every `(name, version)` pair is a separate row.

Comment: Meanwhile: why don't you just try it instead of guessing? If you have your 1.0.4 version ready to go, sdist upload it. Either it will work, and you don't need to ask, or it will give you an error, and then you can ask a more specific and better-researched question about how to work around that problem; it's not obviously going to delete your 1.0.3 or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I would give it a try if I could but this is actually a question in regards to handle a major version change from 1 to 2. So I don't have the working scenario just yet.

Comment: That's what [the test server](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/) is for. (Or you can set up your own local one.)

Comment: Oh! Thank you - will try this.